# Memory problems when using Pubnub Posix C SDK and bcm2835 C library together on raspberry pi

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, pubnub, spi

Has anyone tried to use the [bcm2835](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/) and the [pubnub posix c api](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/posix-c/pubnub-c-sdk) together on a raspberry pi? I'm able to get them both working fine individually, but together I have memory issues. I'm using the bcm2835 for spi communication. Here's my code:

This gets called in main:

```
void inline setup() {
    error = NO_ERROR;
    run = 1;
    spi_setup();
    pb_setup();
}
```

When I call spi_setup() first and then pb_setup(), spi_setup() finishes fine, but pb_setup() gets stuck on pubnub_alloc(), but when I call them in reverse order I immediately get a segfault as soon as I call setup() from my main function. I know it's some sort of memory issue, but have no idea what it could be. I know that pubnub_alloc() dynamically allocates memory for a context to be used to either subscribe or publish to a channel. Could that be the problem?

pb_setup:

```
    void pb_setup() {
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Starting pubnub setup\n");
#endif
    sub_ctx = pubnub_alloc();
    pub_ctx = pubnub_alloc();

    if ((NULL == sub_ctx) && (NULL != pub_ctx)) {
        pubnub_free(pub_ctx);
        error = PUBNUB_INIT_ERROR;
        return;
    } else if ((NULL == pub_ctx) && (NULL != sub_ctx)) {
        pubnub_free(sub_ctx);
        error = PUBNUB_INIT_ERROR;
        return;
    } else if ((NULL == pub_ctx) && (NULL == sub_ctx)) {
        error = PUBNUB_INIT_ERROR;
        return;
    }

    pubnub_init(sub_ctx, PUBNUB_PUB_KEY, PUBNUB_SUB_KEY);
    pubnub_init(pub_ctx, PUBNUB_PUB_KEY, PUBNUB_SUB_KEY);

    pthread_mutex_init(&pb_pubstat.mut, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&pb_substat.mut, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&pb_pubstat.cond, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&pb_substat.cond, NULL);

    pubnub_register_callback(pub_ctx, pb_pub_callback, &pb_pubstat);
    pubnub_register_callback(sub_ctx, pb_sub_callback, &pb_substat);

    pubnub_set_transaction_timeout(pub_ctx, 2000);
    pubnub_set_transaction_timeout(sub_ctx, 900000);

    pb_subscribe();
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("pubnub setup successful");
#endif
}
```

spi_setup:

```
void spi_setup() {
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Starting spi setup\n");
#endif
    if (!bcm2835_init()) {
        error = SPI_INIT_ERROR;
        return;
    }

    if (!bcm2835_spi_begin()) {
        error = SPI_INIT_ERROR;
        return;
    }

    bcm2835_spi_setBitOrder(BCM2835_SPI_BIT_ORDER_MSBFIRST);
    bcm2835_spi_setDataMode(BCM2835_SPI_MODE0);
    bcm2835_spi_setClockDivider(BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_256);
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("spi setup successful\n");
#endif
}
```

Comment: I gave a heads up to our C engineers here at PubNub to review this.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get it working with the pigpio library, but still curious on what might be going on